# Mean free path in spherical coordinate

Tags: kinetic-theory, mean-free-path

I am thinking about a distribution with spatially inhomogeneous cross section in spherical coordinate.
Starting with 1-dimensional case, a change of the flux passing through a slab with length $dx$ is written as

$dI = -In\sigma(x) dx$.

Then the profile of $I(x)$ can be calculated by solving the above equation numerically.

My question is, how should I deal with the same thing in a spherical coordinate? I guess the 1-dimensional case cannot be applied here because the flux will be diluted by the spherical diffusion. I imagine $r^{-2}$ will appear somewhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a topic that I recall was done pretty extensively when I took statistical mechanics, but I have neither my book nor my notes handy to look it up. I recall integrating over steradians a whole bunch though.

Comment: And searching the internet for "steradian mean free path" or "solid angle mean free path" seems to bring up lots of lecture notes on the topic, so maybe that would help you until somebody comes along with an answer.

Comment: Why is a one-dimensional case disallowed in spherical coordinates?  You get to choose the basis onto which you project your results, nature doesn't really care.  In the 1D spherical case, the only variable coordinate would be something like r, right?  Why would that change anything?  If the emitter changes how it distributes the emission, then yes, the geometry will matter.